# Syntax errors when trying to use CString in Visual C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, cstring

My project is not happy regarding include `cstring`. It generates errors like:

```
    Error   10  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'using'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  18  1   fgdll
    Error   95  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanhf'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath    26  1   fgdll
    Error   93  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'tanf'   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cmath    26  1   fgdll
    Error   51  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strxfrm'    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  26  1   fgdll
    Error   49  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strtok' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  26  1   fgdll
    Error   47  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'strstr' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\cstring  25  1   fgdll
...
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try this:

Right click on each piece of code and go to:

`Properties` > `C/C++` > `Advanced` > `Compile As` **and check** `Compile as C++ Code(/TP)`